# Use ADB on Linux to install multiple APKs

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, apk

Passing multipple APKs to ADB script is illegal. This happens when I try to install multiple APK files by calling adb command once only. However, I found a script for Windows machines which installs multiple APKs.

Does anyone know if such script exists for Linux (Ubuntu) machines? I was unable to find it.

I may create one myself, but if such script exists, then it would save me time.

A side note: Passing `adb install *.apk` on some directory does not help as well.

PS. Here is the link where I found a script for Windows ([link](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-multiple-apk-files-automatically-on-android-phones-with-mass-apk-installer/)). I haven't tried this but it seems valid. ;)

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Are you having problems trying to call adb in sucession to `install -r <whatever>.apk` ?

Comment: Switch `-r` means "means reinstall the app, keeping its data". How will it help me? I want to install many APKs via one ADB command

Comment: So rephrase your question to include the single most important requirement that you want, like you did now. [In the original phrasing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13497747/revisions), you didn't mention that, hence why I proposed chaining `adb` calls together in a bash script. ps.: the `-r` switch was just an afterthought to help avoiding overwrite refusals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$ ls -1 *.apk | xargs -l adb install
```

Comment: THANKS!. I totally forgot about `ls -1`